# How to write an R function that evaluates an expression within a data-frame

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

Puzzle for the R cognoscenti: Say we have a data-frame:

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:5, b = 1:5 )
```

I know we can do things like

```
with(df, a)
```

to get a vector of results.

But how do I write a function that takes an expression (such as `a` or `a > 3`) and does the same thing inside. I.e. I want to write a function `fn` that takes a data-frame and an expression as arguments and returns the result of evaluating the expression "within" the data-frame as an environment.

Never mind that this sounds contrived (I could just use `with` as above), but this is just a simplified version of a more complex function I am writing. I tried several variants ( using `eval`, `with`, `envir`, `substitute`, `local`, etc) but none of them work. For example if I define `fn` like so:

```
fn <- function(dat, expr) {
  eval(expr, envir = dat)
}
```

I get this error:

```
> fn( df, a )
Error in eval(expr, envir = dat) : object 'a' not found
```

Clearly I am missing something subtle about environments and evaluation. Is there a way to define such a function?

Comment: There is section on [Hadley's wiki about this topic](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation)

Comment: @Marek that's a great reference to read, thanks!

Comment: Is this page still accessible?

Comment: Is there something wrong with just: `fn <- with`?

Comment: Here is the one from the manual: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html  (2nd edition) and maybe http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html (1st edition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lattice package does this sort of thing in a different way.  See, e.g., `lattice:::xyplot.formula`.

```
fn <- function(dat, expr) {
  eval(substitute(expr), dat)
}
fn(df, a)             # 1 2 3 4 5
fn(df, 2 * a + b)     # 3 6 9 12 15
```

Comment: +1, very nice (didn't think about substitute). The advantage of match.call is that you have all your arguments in a convenient list, which is why I use that one more often. But if you don't need the rest, substitute is indeed a very nice and easy way.

Comment: Is there a way to pass multiple expressions in a list() or c() and evaluate each in a for loop for different data frames which are also stored in a list? I want the same functionality I just can't make it work for dataframes and expressions stored in list.

Comment: @Blind0ne Start a new question describing your problem exactly. You can link back to this question.

Answer (score 10):

That's because you're not passing an expression.

Try:

```
fn <- function(dat, expr) {
  mf <- match.call() # makes expr an expression that can be evaluated
 eval(mf$expr, envir = dat)
}

> df <- data.frame( a = 1:5, b = 1:5 )
> fn( df, a )
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> fn( df, a+b )
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

A quick glance at the source code of functions using this (eg `lm`) can reveal a lot more interesting things about it.

Comment: thanks, that's what I missing! And yes, I tried looking at functions like `subset`, and some others,  to see how how they do it, but they were internals. Didn't think about `lm`, good point for future reference.

Comment: I think using substitute in this circumstance is more canonical. And I'm not sure lm is a good role model - at least make sure to read the standard non-standard evaluation rules.

Comment: @hadley: true. I just thought about `match.call()` and `lm()` because of the `data` argument.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani `subset` isn't internal function, write `subset.data.frame` in console and you'll see how it's made.

Answer (score 2):

A late entry, but the `data.table` approach and syntax would appear to be what you are after.
This is exactly how `[.data.table` works with the `j`, `i` and `by` arguments.

If you need it in the form `fn(x,expr)`, then you can  use the following

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)

`[`(x=DT, j=a)

## [1] 1 2 3 4 5

 `[`(x=DT, j=a * b)
## [1]  2  6 12 20 30
```

I think it is easier to use in more native form

```
DT[,a]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

and so on. In the background this is using `substitute` and `eval`

Answer (score -1):

?within might also be of interest.

```
 df <- data.frame( a = 1:5, b = 1:5 ) 
 within(df, cx <- a > 3)
   a b    cx
 1 1 1 FALSE
 2 2 2 FALSE
 3 3 3 FALSE
 4 4 4  TRUE
 5 5 5  TRUE
```