# R: passing expression to an inner function

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

Further delving into the mysteries of R evaluation...This is closely related to my previous question ( [How to write an R function that evaluates an expression within a data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682709/how-to-write-an-r-function-that-evaluates-an-expression-within-a-data-frame) ). Let's say I want to write a function `topfn` that takes a data-frame and an expression involving column-names of that data-frame. I want to pass both these arguments on to another function `fn` that actually evaluates the expression within the "environment" of the data-frame. *And I want both `fn` and `topfn` to work correctly when passed a data-frame and an expression*

My first attempt, as suggested in the answer to the above question, is to define:

```
 fn <- function(dfr, expr) {
   mf <- match.call()
   eval( mf$expr, envir = dfr )
 }
```

And define `topfn` like this:

```
topfn <- function(df, ex) {
  mf <- match.call()
  fn(df, mf$ex) 
}
```

Now if I have a data-frame

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:5, b = 1:5 )
```

the inner function `fn` works fine:

```
> fn(df,a)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But the `topfn` does not work:

```
> topfn(df,a)
mf$ex
```

To fix this I first check the class of `topfn(df,a)`,

```
> class(topfn(df,a))
[1] "call"
```

This gives me an idea for an ugly hack to re-define `fn` as follows:

```
fn <- function(dfr, expr) {
  mf <- match.call()
  res <- eval(mf$expr, envir = dfr)  
  if(class(res) == 'call')
    eval(expr, envir = dfr) else
  res
}
```

And now both functions work:

```
> fn(df,a)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> topfn(df,a)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

As I said, this looks like an ugly hack. Is there a better way (or more standard idiom) to get these working?
I've consulted Lumley's curiously-named Standard NonStandard Evaluation Rules document http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf but wasn't particularly enlightened after reading it. Also helpful would be any pointers to source-code of functions I can look at for examples.

Comment: There is a great  wiki on the subject of R evaluation by Hadley Wickham here: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation

Comment: And as I suggest there you want carefully distinguish between functions that are used interactively, and functions that are called from other functions.  It is very difficult to call any function that uses substitute and other tricks.  In other words, there is no clean way for both `fn` and `topfn` to work with the same types of inputs - and this a GOOD thing.

Comment: @hadley I see your point: functions designed for interactive use can use substitute/other tricks to make it easy to type them at the console (i.e. no quotes, etc). And functions that are only designed to be called by other functions should not use such tricks because they may break unpredictably. In particular, the solution provided by @Richie at the end of his answer, even though it works in my particular scenario above -- it may break (especially `fn` ) when used in some other scenario -- I think that's what you're saying, right?

Comment: I would be able to give a more concrete advice if you could give more details about what you're trying to achieve - it's too hard to help in the abstract.

Comment: A bit more detail then: For interactive use I wrote a useful function `fn` that takes a time-series data-frame `df` and an expression `expr`, and plots the time-series, highlighting (using `geom_rect`) the periods when the given `expr` evaluates to `TRUE`. Then I wrote another function `topfn`, again for interactive use, that takes more complex inputs, and an expression `ex`, that constructs the data-frame from those inputs, and then calls `fn`, passing it the data-frame and the `ex` to get the plot. So both are meant to be for interactive use, which is why I needed both to work.

Comment: Two options: go the plyr/ggplot route and use a special function quote. . from plyr would probably suit your needs. Otherwise, write a programmer and interactive version of each function: the interactive version captures the expressions and then calls on. Either way will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

Comment: @Hadley, appreciate your advice. I'll take a deeper look at plyr/ggplot2.

Comment: @PrasadChalasani It seems the page on R evaluation has moved here https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is most easily avoided by passing strings into `topfn` instead of expressions.

```
topfn <- function(df, ex_txt) 
{
  fn(df, ex_txt) 
}

fn <- function(dfr, expr_txt) 
{        
   eval(parse(text = expr_txt), dfr) 
}

df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5 )
fn(df, "a")                              
fn(df, "2 * a + b")
topfn(df, "a")             
topfn(df, "2 * a + b")
```

EDIT:

You could let the user pass expressions in, but use strings underneath for your convenience.

Change `topfn` to

```
topfn <- function(df, ex) 
{
  ex_txt <- deparse(substitute(ex))
  fn(df, ex_txt) 
}
topfn(df, a)             
topfn(df, 2 * a + b)
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

This seems to work:

```
topfn <- function(df, ex) 
{
  eval(substitute(fn(df, ex)))
}

fn <- function(dfr, expr) 
{        
   eval(substitute(expr), dfr) 
}
fn(df, a)                              
fn(df, 2 * a + b)
topfn(df, a)             
topfn(df, 2 * a + b)
```

Comment: @richie: Thanks, yes, but I was looking for a way to avoid passing strings. I want the functions to work just like so many other functions in R that take non-quoted expressions as arguments.

Comment: See my answer to the previous question for a third (lattice-style) specification of `fn`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682709/how-to-write-an-r-function-that-evaluates-an-expression-within-a-data-frame

Comment: @Richie Yes I saw that, thanks, it's actually the simplest way to get it to work for the inner function, but adapting it to the nested case above is equally problematic.

Comment: @Richie I saw your update: `topfn` now takes an expression, but the inner `fn` still takes a string. I want both to take expressions. The context is that I wrote a useful function `fn` that takes an expression argument, and I wrote another useful wrapper `topfn` that also takes an expression arg, and I want to pass that to `fn`.

Comment: @Prasad: Hope this version is okay; excess use of `eval` and `substitute` makes my head hurt.

Comment: +1 @Richie for figuring out the right eval/substitute incantation! Thank you... I can now get rid of my ugly hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three dots to gather arguments and pass them to another function, is that what you mean?

```
ftop=function(...) f(...)
f=function(a,b) a[b]

a=data.frame(b=10)

ftop(a,"b")

f(a,"b")
```

Comment: not quite. I don't want to use dots, I want the explicit arguments to be passed on to the inner function.