# Issue with R ggmap zoom and scope?

Tags: r, ggmap

Am I wrong, or is there an issue with the ggmap zoom argument scope? If I run the following it gives me the error object 'thezoom' not found:

```
myfunction<-function(thezoom=14){
  qmap(location = 'baylor university', zoom = thezoom)
}

myfunction()
```

But if thezoom is in the global scope like below it works:

```
thezoom=14
myfunction<-function(){
  qmap(location = 'baylor university', zoom = thezoom)
}

myfunction()
```

I'm trying to write a function that allows the user to specify zoom, but I'm having a little trouble.

Thoughts?

ZR

Comment: There is a pretty extensive discussion of this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692231/r-passing-expression-to-an-inner-function). It has nothing to do with `qmap(...)` specifically.

Comment: @ZRoss So this function is called from inside another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `qmap`, using `get_map` and `ggmap` functions also works.

```
library(ggmap)

myfunction<-function(thezoom=14){
  ggmap(get_map(location = 'baylor university', zoom = thezoom))
}

myfunction()    # Draws a map with zoom set to 14
myfunction(10)  # Draws a map with zoom set to 10
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy, I'm surprised to see that this does indeed work! I appreciate the help. To figure out why, I'll have to follow up with the links that jlhoward points me to. Thanks Sandy, jlhoward and Paulo for giving this thought! ZR