# R: non-standard evaluation with nested functions

Tags: r

I have a function f1 on a dataframe which calls another function f2 and then does stuff with f2's output. f2 works interactively on its own but how do I get it to run when called by f1?

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  z <- f2(x, y)

  # do stuff with z
  w <- z

  return(w)
}
```

f2 uses subset() to de-select certain columns:

```
f2 <- function(x, y) {
  y <- substitute(y)
  subset(x, select = -eval(y))
}
```

As you can see, f2 works interactively. I don't care about that, but I do want it to work when called by f1.

```
# This works fine interactively (but I don't care about that)
f2(mtcars,mpg)

# This is what I want to work
f1(mtcars,mpg)
Error in -eval(y) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

I would prefer not to change f1 or its arguments. How do I re-write f2 so that it works within f1?

Here is a similar question with solutions that I'm having trouble applying to my context: [R: passing expression to an inner function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692231/r-passing-expression-to-an-inner-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use `rlang` and `tidyverse` functions for compatibility with quasiquotation :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(x, y) {
  z <- f2(x, -!!enquo(y))

  # do stuff with z
  w <- z

  return(w)
}

f2 <- function(x, y) {
  select(x, !!enquo(y))
}


f1(mtcars,mpg)
#                     cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4             6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag         6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710            4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# ...
```

This works in base R :

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  z <- f2(x, substitute(y))

  # do stuff with z
  w <- z

  return(w)
}

f2 <- function(x, y) {
  eval(substitute(subset(x, select = -Y), list(Y = y)))
}

f1(mtcars,mpg)
#                     cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4             6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag         6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710            4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version of `rlang` `0.4.0`, we can use the `{{...}}` (curly-curly) that makes it easier to do the evaluation

```
library(rlang)
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  z <- f2(x, -{{y}})

  # do stuff with z
  w <- z

  return(w)
}

f2 <- function(x, y) {
  select(x, {{y}})
}


f1(mtcars,mpg) %>% 
      head
#                  cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```