# Evaluation of multiple expression on data frame

Tags: r

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682709/how-to-write-an-r-function-that-evaluates-an-expression-within-a-data-frame) answer describes how to pass an expression to be evaluated inside a function.

My question:

Is there a way to pass multiple conditions for evaluation?

I have the function for example:

```
createFactor <- function(df, column, condition, label){
  df[column] <- NA      
  for(l in label){
    df[,column][condition] <- l
  }
return(df)
}
```

This is what I've got so far for one condition:

```
set.seed(26)
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
tempMerge_TEST <- createFactor(df,
                          column='V2',
                          condition=df$V1==1,
                          label='medium')
```

Result:

```
  V1     V2 V3 V4 V5
1 NA   <NA>  3  1  5
2  1 medium  1  2  4
3  5   <NA>  3  2  2
4  4   <NA> NA  3  2
5  1 medium  4  4  1
```

But I want this function to work like this:

```
set.seed(26)
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
tempMerge_TEST <- createFactor(df,
                          column='V2',
                          condition=c(df$V1==1, df$V5==5),
                          label=c('medium', 'high'))
```

With the result:

```
  V1     V2 V3 V4 V5
1 NA   high  3  1  5
2  1 medium  1  2  4
3  5   <NA>  3  2  2
4  4   <NA> NA  3  2
5  1 medium  4  4  1
```

I prefer solutions in base R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the following adjustments:

```
createFactor <- function(df, column, condition, label){
  df[column] <- NA      
  for(i in seq_along(label)) {
    df[,column][condition[[i]]] <- label[i]
  }
  return(df)
}

set.seed(26)
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
tempMerge_TEST <- createFactor(df,
                               column='V2',
                               condition=list(df$V1==1, df$V5==5),
                               label=c('medium', 'high'))
```

Note one important difference in how the function was called: changing `condition=c(df$V1==1, df$V5==5)` to `condition=list(df$V1==1, df$V5==5)` (changing `c()` to `list()`). This is necessary because `c()` would concatenate the two conditions, when what you really want is a list of two conditions to work with.

---

Finally, while you wanted a base R solution, the `case_when` function from dplyr is pretty helpful for situations like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(V2 = case_when(V1 == 1 ~ "medium",
                        V5 == 5 ~ "high"))
```